# Does taking the tensor product with $\mathbb{Z}$ really do nothing?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, tensor-products

I have a proof that $\mathbb{Z} \otimes A \cong A$ for abelian group $A$, but have a hard time believing this is true since the left group seems to have a lot more elements. The isomorphism I have found is

$z \otimes a \mapsto a + ... + a$ ($z$ times) and then extends linearly and for the inverse

$a \mapsto 1 \otimes a$. We certainly have $z \otimes a \mapsto a + ... + a \mapsto 1 \otimes a + ... + 1 \otimes a = z \otimes a$ and $a \mapsto 1 \otimes a \mapsto a$.

I think the first one is a homomorphism because $(z + w) \otimes a \mapsto a + ... + a$ ($z + w$ times) which is what $z \otimes a + w \otimes a$ maps to and $z \otimes (a + b) \mapsto a + b + ... + a + b = a + ... + a + b + ... + b$ which is what $z \otimes a + z \otimes b$ maps to, and we extend linearly.

The second one is homo because $1 \otimes (a + b) = 1 \otimes a + 1 \otimes b$.

Comment: Note that $z \otimes a = 1 \otimes (za)$ for any $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ by definition of the relations on tensor products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n\in\mathbb N$ and $a\in A$, then$$n\otimes a=1\otimes(na)\text{ and }(-n)\otimes a=1\otimes(-na).$$So, no, $\mathbb Z\bigotimes A$ doesn't have more elements than $A$. Each of its elements is of the form $1\otimes a$ for some $a\in A$.

And, yes, your proof is correct.

Comment: Thanks, that helped my intuition with the tensor product a lot.